# Custom order with NSFetchedResultsController and list headers

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm coding a sectioned table with headers. I use NSFetchedResultsController to fetch data from core data, but I can't figure out how to do it.

Let's say my core data is a collection of stadiums:

**Stadium**

```
name
city
zip_code
```

and I have these objects:

```
 Yankee Stadium, Baltimore, 30301
 Zoulou Stadium, Baltimore, 30301
 Charlie Stadium, Baltimore, 30305
 Tango Stadium, New-York, 10007
 Echo Stadium, Atlanta, 45036
```

I want:

1. the stadiums of Baltimore first, with 1 section for each zip code
2. then the other cities sorted by alphabetical order, with 1 section for each city

so the result in my list should be:

```
 --------------------------------
 Baltimore 1st district
 --------------------------------
 Yankee Stadium, Baltimore, 30301
 Zoulou Stadium, Baltimore, 30301

 --------------------------------
 Baltimore 5th district
 --------------------------------
 Charlie Stadium, Baltimore, 30305

 --------------------------------
 Atlanta
 --------------------------------
 Echo Stadium, Atlanta, 45036

 --------------------------------
 New-York
 --------------------------------
 Tango Stadium, New-York, 10007
```

What is the solution? I think that I can't set up such a complex order in NSFetchedResultsController

Thanks for your help.

PS: I'm an Android dev, and in my world it's easily done with a Comparator.

Comment: anyone? it's hard to fix this